# EmberJS : Call parent class function from child class init method

Tags: ember.js

I have a parent class

```
MyBaseClass = Ember.Object.extend({
  getData:function() {
    return someData;
  }
})
```

and a child class that when created needs to call a function in parent class

```
MyChildClass = MyBaseClass.extend({
  sampleData:[],
  init:function(){
     this._super();
    Ember.set(this, 'sampleData', this.getData());
  }
})
```

My problem is, when i run this code i get "Uncaught TypeError: this.getData is not a function".

Any idea why this is happening? Or fix to this.

Comment: Yours is working in [my twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7d34759b6c2f96cb50a02b70c73e6c9e?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C) it would be good if you share where are you using `MyChildClass ` or any non working twiddle

Comment: problem is that, when i add `this._super(...arguments);`, it breaks minification with error " _Failed to minify the input javascript source: this language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT6 mode or better: spread expression. Use --language_in=ECMASCRIPT6 or ECMASCRIPT6_STRICT to enable ES6 features._ "

Comment: so you are having this file in vendor folder. Am I right?. no problem in this case without super call it should work..Mostly super call is necessary when we are extending Framework class like `Ember.Component` . refer https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/#toc_initializing-instances . Have a look at my twiddle update your code in replicate the issue. it will help us to identify the issue

Comment: Yeah.. I am working on a Spring-boot project that has EmberJS in it. I don't see any difference in your twiddle code and mine. Let me go though the code again.

Answer (score 0):

Write your `init` method this way without using ES6 syntax:

```
init: function() {
  this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  Ember.set(this, 'sampleData', this.getData());
```